# Pauli Basis Matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, definition, conventions

When I search for the [Pauli basis matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) I find both the following sets but I wonder which one is the right one and why does the first set have an imaginary term which is absent in the second set.

**First Set**

[image]

**Second Set**

[image]

Comment: What is the source for the second set?

Comment: Whatever they are, the second set are *not* Pauli matrices.  They are a trace-orthonormal basis set for 2 by 2 matrices, however.

Comment: This is where I found the second set and it is termed as the "Pauli bais": https://earth.esa.int/documents/653194/656796/Polarimetric_Decompositions.pdf

Comment: The first set are what is normally meant by 'the' Pauli matrices. I've not heard them called 'the Pauli basis' really, even though they are a basis of the traceless hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The first set of matrices are what is conventionally called the Pauli matrices. The identity matrix is sometimes included as a Pauli matrix $\sigma_0$. With this included, we have a correspondence between the two sets of matrices:

$S_a= \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \sigma_0
\\S_b= \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \sigma_3
\\S_c= \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \sigma_1
\\S_d= \frac {-i} {\sqrt 2} \sigma_2$

Apart from the common factor of $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$, the only other difference is the factor of $-i$ which makes the elements of $S_d$ real. Why is this significant ? The Pauli matrices are both [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) i.e. $\sigma_n^\dagger = \sigma_n$ and [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) i.e. $\sigma_n^\dagger = \sigma_n^{-1}$. As a result they are [involutory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) i.e. $\sigma_n^2=I$.

$\sqrt 2 S_d$ is unitary since

$(\sqrt 2 S_d)^\dagger = (\sqrt 2 S_d)^T = (\sqrt 2 S_d)^{-1}$

However $\sqrt 2 S_d$ is not Hermitian or involutory since

$(\sqrt 2 S_d)^\dagger = (\sqrt 2 S_d)^{-1} = -(\sqrt 2 S_d)
\\ \Rightarrow (\sqrt 2 S_d)^2 = -I$

Since $(\sqrt 2 S_d)$ is not Hermitian and not involutory it cannot be a Pauli matrix.